# What's the meaning of "of Gates" in "of Gates being a member of a plot"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context, gerunds

> The falsehoods being spread vary, but range from him creating COVID-19 in order to profit from a vaccine, or **of Gates** being a member of a plot to cull humanity and/or implement a global surveillance system.

Could anyone help me figure out why the author used "of" here? Is the function of "of Gates" here same with a possessive form(Gates') - to specify the "doer" of the gerund phrases? Thanks:)

This is a sentence from a [article](https://www.theverge.com/2020/4/17/21224728/bill-gates-coronavirus-lies-5g-covid-19) on The verge.

Answer (score 1):

You have caught an error in the structure of the sentence.

They have started with "range from him creating...", and should have continued at some point with "to him being a member...".

I suspect an incomplete edit inserted "of Gates" in place of "him", and the preceding part of the sentence was not corrected to correspond with that change.

Comment: Just an afterthought - published books are usually proofread and mostly error-free. Newspapers and magazines used to be as well. However, online articles often have errors, because of not being proofed, and because the ease of editing with a computer can lead to incomplete edits.